# How to embed a function returning a string in a Q query?

Tags: kdb

I'm using `Q.f` to format column fields from integer to float with 4 digits precision:

```
fmt_price:{[val] .Q.f[4;](val*0.0001)}
select fmt_price[price] from mytable
```

The `fmt_price` works well at the q prompt, but if I embed the function in a query I get this error:

> An error occurred during execution of the query. The server sent the
>   response: `type

The `fmt_price` call works if I return a float or integer variable, rather than the result of `Q.f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an each over the list. Currently you are passing a list of values to .Q.f, when it expects an atom. Something like the following is what you need:

```
fmt_price:{[val] .Q.f[4;] each (val*0.0001)}
```

Comment: Could be simplified to `{4 .Q.f'x*.0001}`. Or indeed the function can be removed entirely: `select 4 .Q.f'price*.0001 from mytable`.